# SPARQL query to extract Wikipedia infobox data using DBPedia

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

How to extract the **infobox data** for a Wikipedia page using **DBPedia**? It would be great if any one can **directly provide me with the query I can run at the DBPedia end-point** to get the infobox contents as a key-value pair of **property-value**. For example,

Querying for Mahatma Gandhi should return something like:

**Birth Date : 1869-10-02

Birth Name : Mohandas K. Gandhi,

Resting Place : Delhi,

Death Date : 1948-01-30**

Since this is only a small part of the project I am working on, I am avoiding getting into the details of SPARQL, etc.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a “give me the code” service.

Comment: @svick Yup, I understand. I was trying to write my own parser that parses the data received through the WikiMedia API to extract the infobox . Sadly, given the huge number of infobox templates, that method is not fool-proof and guaranteed to work for all kinds of boxes. So, was looking for a quick fix to the problem using DBPedia. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your URI is  dbpedia.org/resource/Mahatma_Gandhi (coming from  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi) you can simply do:

```
select * {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mahatma_Gandhi> dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate;
dbpedia-owl:birthName ?name;
dbpedia-owl:restingPlace ?restingPlace;
dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?deathDate
 }
```

try it on http://dbpedia.org/sparql
[(direct link)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%2a%20%7B%0D%0A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FMahatma_Gandhi%3E%20dbpedia-owl%3AbirthDate%20%3FbirthDate%3B%0D%0Adbpedia-owl%3AbirthName%20%3Fname%3B%0D%0Adbpedia-owl%3ArestingPlace%20%3FrestingPlace%3B%0D%0Adbpedia-owl%3AdeathDate%20%3FdeathDate%0D%0A%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

if you will query for other resources I suggest you something like this

```
select * {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mahatma_Gandhi> dbpedia-owl:birthName ?name.
OPTIONAL{<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mahatma_Gandhi> dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate}
OPTIONAL{<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mahatma_Gandhi> dbpedia-owl:restingPlace ?restingPlace}
OPTIONAL{<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mahatma_Gandhi> dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?deathDate}
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you use the `dbpedia-owl:` prefix, but avoid the `dbpedia:` one that would make `dbpedia:Mahatma_Gandhi` much easier to type and read?

Comment: @dvcama Thanks, the answer is helpful. However, is there a way to get the **entire** infobox data without having to **explicitly mention** each property like above where you mentioned "birthdate", "restingPlace", "deathDate". 
Something like, you specify the resource : "Mahatma Gandhi" and you get all the properties and the values that exist for that resource.
I need the infoboxes for a wide range of things from "Nile" to "Mahatma Gandhi" to "Bacteria", so mentioning the properties explicitly would be difficult.

Comment: Hi, as Gabriel wrote you can do a describe query, I prefer to use `select * {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mahatma_Gandhi> ?p ?o }` because I don't want inverse relations

Answer (score 2):

You can extract all the data concerning Gandhi with one request :

```
describe <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mahatma_Gandhi>
```

And choose the results format.